# Go to outer else statement when inner if condition fails

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have:

```
const apple = 1;
const banna = "apple";

if (apple === 1 || banana === "apple") {
    if (banana === "orange") {
        console.log("Yes it is orange");
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
else {
    console.log("No not orange");
}
```

In the provided example, I want to execute the outer `else` condition when the nested `if` in the first `if` fails. Here, the example I have used is simple, in my use case it is completely different.

Let me know if anybody needs any further information.

Comment: have you tried `else if( )` ?

Comment: `if ((apple === 1 || banana === "apple") && (banana === "orange")){`

Comment: Also, double check your variable names `banna` != `banana`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `break` to an `else`, no. You have to reformulate your conditions. The logical reformulation of what you've written is simply:

```
if (apple === 1 && banana === "orange") {
    console.log('Yes it is orange')
} else {
    console.log("No not orange")
}
```

...since it's impossible for `banana` to be both `"orange"` and `"apple"` simultaneously, but of course your example was just an example. If there were more conditions, you could use `else if`:

```
if (x || y) {
    // `x` or `y` was true (`z` may or may not also be true)
} else if (z) {
    // `z` is true and `x` and `y` were not true
} else {
    // None of them was true
}
```

or

```
if (z) {
    // `z` is true (`x` or `y` may also be true)
} else if (x || y) {
    // `x` or `y` was true (`z` was not true)
} else {
    // None of them was true
}
```

*(I've used "true" above in its logical sense, not its strict JavaScript boolean sense. Conditions in JavaScript use truthiness vs. falsiness, not strict true/false. `if (1)` will go into the `if` body, because `1` is a truthy value; `if (0)` will not go into the `if` body because `0` is a falsy value. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `false` [of course], and on browsers `document.all` [strange but true]; all other values are truthy.)*

Answer (score 0):

You could simply join the two `if`s in to a single condition:

```js
const apple = 1
const banana = "apple" // correct spelling!

if ((apple === 1 || banana === "apple") && (banana === "orange")){
        console.log('Yes it is orange')
} else {
    console.log("No not orange")
}
```

Although the double test on `banana` is a little redundant in this case and could be equally written as:

```js
if (apple === 1 && banana === "orange"){
```